# How to parse travis_time:start into normal datestamp?

Tags: datetime, travis-ci

I'm  delving into the travis-ci.org logs of a very simple app that was built to demonstrate testing and continuous integration.

I see timestamps given in each raw log file, but I don't know a simple way to convert them to readable dates? 
There seem to be two different formats. 
I'm  on a mac, so bash or python or an online calculator answer would be terrific.
thank you!

Here are the 4 sub-builds, each for a different jvm:

4.1 https://travis-ci.org/ihassin/cucumber-jvm/jobs/40111229

`travis_time:end:121a64f6:start=1415224070390184790,finish=1415224071568557470,duration=1178372680`

4.2 https://travis-ci.org/ihassin/cucumber-jvm/jobs/40111230

`0Ktravis_time:start:094d841c`

4.3 https://travis-ci.org/ihassin/cucumber-jvm/jobs/40111231

`travis_time:start:00067b60`

4.4
https://travis-ci.org/ihassin/cucumber-jvm/jobs/40111232

`travis_time:start:0011ba85`

Answer (score 1):

The timestamps are in nanoseconds. To get a normal Unix timestamp, you need to divide them by 10^6. For the value `finish=1415224071568557470`, for example, in JavaScript you could do:

```js
new Date(1415224071568557470 / 1e6).toUTCString() // 'Wed, 05 Nov 2014 21:47:51 GMT'
```

Comment: Actually, the timestamps are in nanoseconds. The code example you gave works because the "Date()" constructor in Javascript expects a date in milliseconds already, a factor 1000000 larger.